# Disable Focus to Browser

Tags: asp.net

Can any one tell how to disable focus to a browser.
Hi i am currently working in .net application and i need to disable the tab focus to browser objects such as toolbars,address bar, since the user will not be using these components often

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't do this, it breaks what the user expects a webpage to do.  Messing with the fundamental behavior breaks several things:

- My tab button and where I expect it to go
- Screen readers for the disabled
- Trust in your application

In some cases, you need to ask **why?** before asking **how?**, this is one of those.  Anything that behaves differently from the other 99.9999% of the web is broken in the eyes of your user.

Comment: I don't think it can be done, anyway. Good points however... +1

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo - Oh it can be with a few lines of jQuery, but it's not something I'd ever do.

Comment: @Nick: Can JavaScript really prevent the user from getting the focus on the address bar?... Or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Daniel - From tabbing to it yes, it can't prevent it all-together.

Comment: Ok I get it... "Prevent the user from 'tabbing' out of the document "... I agree, it's not something we should do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I agree with Nick Craver. If you have to disable due to some crap requirements, then try opening a new window without toolbar, editable address bar etc and load the page inside the newly opened window.